# Bitmap Image as a dictionary key

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

I want to know what size should be the image to use it as a hashset/dictionary key. I'm also thinking about using hash functions for this purpose but i'm afraid of hash collisions. I need to store about  million of images.

Comment: But what do you use as the key? The first x number of bytes? What if the images are mostly identical? Then you could have a lot of collisions that make your HashTable act more like a linked list. Not to mention, what does the Equals function look like? Don't you have to compare *all* the bytes to test for equality in the case of collision? It seems to me either you're going to have a really slow hash function (with few collisions), or a really fast hash function, with lots of collisions, and a really slow Equals function. I agree with @Roy Dictus: don't use the image itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bitmap image as a key? That's not a very good idea. Hashset keys should be as small as possible, otherwise performance will suffer significantly.

What you can do is calculate a hash value (say a SHA1) from the image, and then use that as the key. It's only 20 bytes so that should be a good size, much better than a full bitmap image anyway.

Comment: No need to downvote this answer, it is correct! And if you do downvote, at least have the decency to explain why.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what data you use for key in a HashSet or Dictionary, but you need to implement a `GetHashCode` and an `Equals` method for it.

Hash collisions is not a problem. That will just put the two images in the same bucket, and use the `Equals` method to find the right image.

Answer (score 1):

Given your Image's bytes, you can use an algorithm such as MD5 or SHA1 to calculate a hash for it.

Example with `bytes` being your picture's byte array:

```
using (var md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    var hash = Convert.ToBase64String(md5.ComputeHash(bytes));
    //Store hash
}
```