# How to solve problem of unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, typeerror, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to do this:

```py
for myimage in Images:
    image = cv2.imread(myimage)  
    processed_image = Image_Preprocessing(image) 

    name = os.path.basename(myimage) # Get image name to save it as a Class
    class_name = str(name) 
    Image_count= Image_count+1

    # To divide the image to mxm patches
    for r in range(0,processed_image.shape[0],patch_size):
        for c in range(0,processed_image.shape[1],patch_size):
             value= processed_image[r:r+patch_size, c:c+patch_size]


             #Search for similar patch 
             #if the value already exists in dict only update the classes list
             #else add the value in dict and update the classes list 
             if any((value == patch).all() for patch in Patches_dic.keys()):
                if (class_name in Patches_dic[value] ):  
                    continue
                else:
                    Patches_dic[value].append(class_name) 
             else:
                 list_Of_Classes.append(class_name)
                 Patches_dic.update({value : list_Of_Classes })   #Key: image patch  Value: List of Classes
```

However, I got this error

> Patches_dic.update({tuple(value) : list_Of_Classes })
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

I did not know what I'm doing wrong and how to solve this problem :(

Comment: You can use a `ndarray` (and many other complex types) as a key in a dictionary, as a value it is ok.

Comment: you are trying to use an array as a dictionary key.  That can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @hpaulj. Dictionary keys cannot be list-type objects like `ndarrays` or `list`.

From the code provided, I am guessing that `value` stores a part of image, which are in `ndarray` format. Hence if you want to keep it as a key, try hashing it and making the hash of the image as the key. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915954/bitmap-image-as-a-dictionary-key) to know how to properly make representation of image as a key.